# LVM2 Integrity feature breaks LV activation?

Tags: systemd, lvm, udev, raid, integrity

I've been trying to enable the integrity feature on my new LVM2 volumes. I use a command like this to create the lv:

```
sudo lvcreate --type raid1 --mirrors 1 --size 20g --raidintegrity y --name RAID MY_VG
```

The lv appears to be created successfully and I can see it building itself in the `Cpy%Sync` output of `lvs`. All seems to go well and it eventually reaches 100%.

I can create a filesystem (been playing with xfs and btrfs), I can mount it, write to it and the volume appears to be working flawlessly. I updated fstab and it mounts and unmounts smoothly with a simple `sudo mount -a` for example.

##### Then I reboot and the logical volume is never auto activated

So fstab cannot find the filesystem to mount. I can fix this manually with a simple `sudo vgchange -ay MY_VG` and then a `sudo mount -a` but something seems wrong because...

##### This is only a problem for Logical Volumes with Integrity enabled.

I created a second logical volume without integrity (and that is the only difference):

```
 sudo lvcreate --type raid1 --mirrors 1 --size 20g --raidintegrity n --name RAID_TEST MY_VG
```

And after reboot RAID_TEST is activated and available to be mounted immediately, but my original logical volume with integrity (named just RAID) is still deactivated at boot. So because this test LV is activated I know there is nothing wrong with the PVs nor the VG. The issue has to be with the LV configuration with integrity but I can't find any docs that suggest I am doing anything wrong.

I have reproduced this on 2 different servers with various different combinations and the results are always the same and its only the volumes with integrity enabled that behave this way and never auto-activate. Zero obvious errors in system logs, journalctl, nor systemctl status of any lvm units.

What is going on?

I can see zero errors with the devices or lvm when I check journalctl. The only output all looks normal (and its the exact same log messages for every logical volume and volume group in my system regardless of whether its a volume with integrity enabled).

At this point I am wondering if integrity is actually a ready-to-use feature of LVM2. My experience has been extremely janky with very very poor documentation. The man pages for [lvchange with respect to integrity features](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvchange.8.html#OPTIONS) conflict with the [raw source code of lvchange](https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/blob/6d1e894a867681af7a811ed63bc435f3aa55fec8/tools/lvchange.c#L1736) (which I eventually had to go read the flipping source). The source code also contradicts the [RedHat documentation around lvm integrity](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/assembly_configure-mange-raid-configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes#proc-scrubbing-raid-volume-configure-manage-raid). None of that explains why this is happening though.

Can anyone help? It would be very appreciated. At this point it feels like I need to abandon LVM if I want integrity protection.

Comment: normally udev is supposed to trigger calls to vgchange once all PV of a VG are present, if that does not happen but it works when done manually, maybe those udev rules are failing somehow for you, or if the problem occurs in initramfs stage, there might be some kernel module missing for your use case... maybe a question for the linux-lvm mailing list?

Comment: It looks like the scan completes smoothly, which makes it all the more frustrating: `PV /dev/sdc online, VG MY_VG is complete.` and it successfully auto-activates the non-integrity volume in the group just fine. It really feels like a bug at this point, but I'm not sure where to actually get in touch with the right team

Comment: Are all the kernel modules required to support the integrity feature available in initramfs? If not, that might explain why the automatic activation fails but later manual activation is successful.

Comment: @telcoM That seems very promising! A google for required lvm modules led me to a [report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=989221) by a user with the same behaviour who fixed it by correcting their loaded modules. I'm going by the modules listed in their suggested patch but I'm very curious how someone discovers the needed kernel moduels in this scenario? If it wasn't for this bug report I would be struggling I think. I am at work now but will report back later if this worked. I did quickly check and saw my system indeed did not have the suggested dm modules loaded.

Comment: tested and it does indeed auto activate after I added dm_integrity to the initramfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic LVM activation happens very early in the boot process, often when the system is still running on initramfs. If the modules required for the integrity feature are not included in initramfs, that would explain why the automatic activation fails but a manual activation later (when the normal root filesystem is in use) is successful.

When the system has just booted up and failed to activate the VG, run `lsmod` and note the name of the top-most module in the list. Then activate the VG manually, run `lsmod` again, and there should be some modules added to the top of the module list. Those are the modules the system needed to load for activating the integrity-enabled VG, and couldn't find in initramfs. Then do whatever is necessary to tell your initramfs generator to always include those modules, and rebuild your initramfs.

Comment: Indeed! On Debian 12 "bookworm" I put `dm_integrity` into `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and after `update-initramfs -u` autoactivation worked. — I'd also like to share an issue I've discovered: if `/boot`'s partition is a LV, then there *must not* be a raidintegrity LV anywhere before that LV inside the same VG. Otherwise, `update-grub` will show an error (`disk \`lvmid/.../...' not found`) and GRUB cannot boot. So it's best if you put `/boot` into its own VG. (PS: Errors like `unknown node '..._rimage_0` can be ignored.)